# How do I create , test (and if possible deploy) a django project using only an android 10 device?

Tags: django

How do I create,test(and if possible deploy) a django project using only an android 10 device?

Comment: Are you trying to code a django website on your phone? That seems quite tedious and inefficient in both the writing of code and debugging it. I did find [this article](https://dev.to/coledrain/how-i-ran-django-on-my-android-phone-k4a), but this seems difficult and unproductive. Alongside this, this forum is for specific questions, so I would recommend narrowing your question down a bit.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a choice for now.  Thanks anyway.